# Subscribing to ROS and Gazebo topic in one node (ROS callback failing)

Tags: ros, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I have a node which successfully subscribes to a contacts topic in Gazebo. Now I want the same node to subscribe to a ROS topic which of course runs through a separate callback. Unfortunately the ROS callback is not being run even though the topic is available and publishing. Only the Gazebo callback is running. Is there something I'm missing here? Are the publishers/subscribers from ROS and Gazebo conflicting?

Of course I asked this question on the Gazebo answers page as well but seeing as it is the ROS subscriber that is not working, I was hoping someone could tip me why the callback could not be running.

Here is my code:

```
#include <gazebo/transport/transport.hh>
#include <gazebo/msgs/msgs.hh>
#include <gazebo/gazebo.hh>
#include <nav_msgs/Odometry.h>
#include <ros/ros.h>
#include <geometry_msgs/Vector3.h>

#include <iostream>

ros::Publisher pub;
bool airborne;

// Forces callback function
void forcesCb(ConstContactsPtr &_msg){
    geometry_msgs::Vector3 msgForce;
    // What to do when callback
    if ( _msg->contact_size()!= 0){
        // Now publish
        msgForce.x = _msg->contact(0).wrench().Get(0).body_1_wrench().force().x();
        msgForce.y = _msg->contact(0).wrench().Get(0).body_1_wrench().force().y();
        msgForce.z = _msg->contact(0).wrench().Get(0).body_1_wrench().force().z();
        pub.publish(msgForce);
    } else if (airborne = false) {
        msgForce.x = 0;
        msgForce.y = 0;
        msgForce.z = 0;
    } else {
        msgForce.x = 0;
        msgForce.y = 0;
        msgForce.z = 0;
    }
    pub.publish(msgForce);
}

// Position callback function
void positionCb(const nav_msgs::Odometry::ConstPtr& msg2){
    if (msg2->pose.pose.position.z > 0.3) {
        airborne = true;
    } else {
        airborne = false;
    }
}

int main(int _argc, char **_argv){
  // Set variables
  airborne = false;

  // Load Gazebo & ROS
  gazebo::setupClient(_argc, _argv);
  ros::init(_argc, _argv, "force_measure");

  // Create Gazebo node and init
  gazebo::transport::NodePtr node(new gazebo::transport::Node());
  node->Init();

  // Create ROS node and init
  ros::NodeHandle n;
  pub = n.advertise<geometry_msgs::Vector3>("forces", 1000);

  // Listen to Gazebo contacts topic
  gazebo::transport::SubscriberPtr sub = node->Subscribe("~/quadrotor/base_link/quadrotor_bumper/contacts", forcesCb);

  // Listen to ROS for position
  ros::Subscriber sub2 = n.subscribe("ground_truth/state", 1000, positionCb);

  // Busy wait loop...replace with your own code as needed.
  while (true)
    gazebo::common::Time::MSleep(20);

  // Spin ROS (needed for publisher)
  ros::spinOnce();

  // Mayke sure to shut everything down.
  gazebo::shutdown();
}
```

---

Update:

CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8 FATAL_ERROR)
project(force_measure)

include (FindPkgConfig)
if (PKG_CONFIG_FOUND)
  pkg_check_modules(GAZEBO gazebo)
endif()

include(FindBoost)
find_package(Boost ${MIN_BOOST_VERSION} REQUIRED system filesystem regex)

find_package(Protobuf REQUIRED)
find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS roscpp gazebo_msgs geometry_msgs nav_msgs)

catkin_package()

include_directories(${GAZEBO_INCLUDE_DIRS})
link_directories(${GAZEBO_LIBRARY_DIRS})

add_executable(listener listener.cpp)
add_executable(listener2 listener2.cpp)

target_link_libraries(listener ${GAZEBO_LIBRARIES} ${Boost_LIBRARIES} ${PROTOBUF_LIBRARIES} pthread)
target_link_libraries(listener2 ${catkin_LIBRARIES} ${GAZEBO_LIBRARIES} ${Boost_LIBRARIES} ${PROTOBUF_LIBRARIES} pthread)
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/214814/subscribing-to-ros-and-gazebo-topic-in-one-node-(ros-callback-failing)/) by [niall](https://answers.ros.org/users/22476/niall/) on ROS Answers with karma: 47 on 2015-07-29

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [cyborg-x1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1900/cyborg-x1/) on 2015-07-29**:
Did you check rqt_graph? So that your node is connected to the right topic?
You do not have a "/" in the beginning so there could be: `<possible namespace>/ground_truth/state` or something like that

**Comment by [niall](https://answers.ros.org/users/22476/niall/) on 2015-07-29**:
Good questions, thanks! I did check rqt_graph indeed and force_measure (this node) is connected (and receiving) topic `/ground_state/state` from node `ground_truth`. I also did try the "/", in fact I had it that way before but that also didn't help.

**Comment by [polde](https://answers.ros.org/users/32229/polde/) on 2017-10-24**:
Hi. I know this may be an old question.
How to make "#include <gazebo/transport/transport.hh>" generate no error?
What do I have to modify in order to let this library properly work?
Thanks

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2017-10-24**:
@polde You'll probably have better luck getting an answer by asking a new question.

**Comment by [niall](https://answers.ros.org/users/22476/niall/) on 2017-10-25**:
@polde What are you trying to do? This include was never the issue for me (as explained below). I presume you're not including the library in exactly that way (with all the extra quotes)?

**Comment by [AyaO](https://answers.ros.org/users/38650/ayao/) on 2018-11-21**:
Hi, Can you share the CMakeLists.txt of your program ? because I want to implement a similar program but I have a problem when executing catkin_make caused by the CmakeLists.txt

**Comment by [niall](https://answers.ros.org/users/22476/niall/) on 2018-11-21**:
Sure. But I'll have to dig it up out of a zip far far away. Give me a few days.

In the meantime, what "problem" is catkin_make giving you?

**Comment by [niall](https://answers.ros.org/users/22476/niall/) on 2018-12-01**:
@AyaO

See below:
https://pastebin.com/f5n6B3za

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2018-12-01**:
@niall I updated your question to include the code from the pastebin in order to keep the question self-contained in case that site goes down or the pastebin disappears.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Your problem is here:

```
  // Busy wait loop...replace with your own code as needed.
  while (true)
    gazebo::common::Time::MSleep(20); //<<< That is your only while loop ;-)

  // Spin ROS (needed for publisher) 
  ros::spinOnce();//<< executed at the end only once...
```

try:

```
  // Busy wait loop...replace with your own code as needed.
  while (true)
  {
     gazebo::common::Time::MSleep(20);

  // Spin ROS (needed for publisher) // (nope its actually for subscribers-calling callbacks ;-) )
  ros::spinOnce();

     ...
  }
```

---

Originally posted by [cyborg-x1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1900/cyborg-x1/) with karma: 1376 on 2015-07-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [niall](https://answers.ros.org/users/22476/niall/) on 2015-07-29**:
Simple and effective, stupid mistake.. Thanks a bunch!

**Comment by [cyborg-x1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1900/cyborg-x1/) on 2015-07-29**:
Welcome ;-)